# Exporting xlsx file can,t open Error "Invalid file format or Extension"

Tags: c#, excel, apache-poi

With Apache POI to 3.15 I am exporting .xlsx file using SXSSFWorkbook but its exporting corrupted file.MS Excel failed to open file with File format or extension not valid error.
Anybody can help what I am doing wrong here ?

Code is:

```
public void exportToExcel(FacesContext facesContext, OutputStream
   outputStream) {
                Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();

                CreationHelper createHelper = wb.getCreationHelper();
                Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet("RouteDetails");
                Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
                Cell cell = row.createCell(0);

                Font font = wb.createFont();
                font.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 9);
                font.setFontName("Courier New");
                font.setItalic(true);
                font.setBold(true);
                CellStyle style = wb.createCellStyle();
                style.setFont(font);
                cell.setCellStyle(style);
                cell.setCellValue("Route Detail Import Export Template");
                Row r1 = sheet.createRow(1);
                Cell c1 = r1.createCell(0);
                c1.setCellStyle(style);
                c1.setCellValue("Route Id");
                Cell c11 = r1.createCell(1);
                c11.setCellValue(getRouteId());
                Row r2 = sheet.createRow(2);
                Cell c2 = r2.createCell(0);
                c2.setCellStyle(style);
                c2.setCellValue("Route Name");
                Cell c12 = r2.createCell(1);
                c12.setCellValue("ABC");

                Row r3 = sheet.createRow(3);
                Cell c3 = r3.createCell(0);
                c3.setCellStyle(style);
                c3.setCellValue("Salesman");
                Cell c13 = r3.createCell(1);
                c13.setCellValue(route.getSalesmanId() + route.getName());


                Row r5 = sheet.createRow(4);
                Cell c5 = r5.createCell(0);
                c5.setCellStyle(style);
                c5.setCellValue("WeekNumber");
                Cell c15 = r5.createCell(1);
                c15.setCellValue(getWeekNo());
                Row r6 = sheet.createRow(5);
                Cell c6 = r6.createCell(0);
                c6.setCellStyle(style);
                c6.setCellValue("Year");
                Cell c16 = r6.createCell(1);
                c16.setCellValue(getYear());
                Row r7 = sheet.createRow(6);
                Cell c7 = r7.createCell(0);
                c7.setCellStyle(style);
                c7.setCellValue("Date");
                CellStyle cellStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
                cellStyle.setDataFormat(createHelper.createDataFormat().getFormat("m/d/yy"));
                Cell c8 = r7.createCell(1);
                c8.setCellValue(new Date());
                c8.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
                Row r9 = sheet.createRow(7);
                Cell c9 = r9.createCell(0);
                c9.setCellValue("");
                Row detRow = sheet.createRow(8);
                cell.setCellStyle(style);
                cell = detRow.createCell(0);
                cell.setCellStyle(style);
                cell.setCellValue("Customer Code");
                cell = detRow.createCell(1);
                cell.setCellStyle(style);
                cell.setCellValue("Customer Name");
                cell = detRow.createCell(2);
                cell.setCellStyle(style);
                cell.setCellValue("Remarks");
                cell = detRow.createCell(3);
                cell.setCellStyle(style);
                cell.setCellValue("Frequency");
                cell = detRow.createCell(4);
                cell.setCellStyle(style);
                cell.setCellValue("Sunday");
                cell = detRow.createCell(5);
                cell.setCellStyle(style);
                cell.setCellValue("Monday");
                cell = detRow.createCell(6);
                cell.setCellStyle(style);
                cell.setCellValue("Tuesday");
                cell = detRow.createCell(7);
                cell.setCellStyle(style);
                cell.setCellValue("Wednesday");
                cell = detRow.createCell(8);
                cell.setCellStyle(style);
                cell.setCellValue("Thursday");
                cell = detRow.createCell(9);
                cell.setCellStyle(style);
                cell.setCellValue("Friday");
                cell = detRow.createCell(10);
                cell.setCellStyle(style);
                cell.setCellValue("Saturday");

                // Write the output to a file
                for (int i = 0; i < getDetails().size(); i++) {
                    Row detailRow = sheet.createRow(i + 9);
                    RouteDetail det = getDetails().get(i);
                    detailRow.createCell(0).setCellValue(det.getCustomerCode());
                    detailRow.createCell(1).setCellValue(det.getCustomerName());
                    detailRow.createCell(2).setCellValue(det.getRemarks());
                    detailRow.createCell(3).setCellValue(det.getFrequency());
                    detailRow.createCell(4).setCellValue(det.getSun());
                    detailRow.createCell(5).setCellValue(det.getMon());
                    detailRow.createCell(6).setCellValue(det.getTue());
                    detailRow.createCell(7).setCellValue(det.getWed());
                    detailRow.createCell(8).setCellValue(det.getThu());
                    detailRow.createCell(9).setCellValue(det.getFri());
                    detailRow.createCell(10).setCellValue(det.getSat());


                }

                sheet.autoSizeColumn(0);
                sheet.autoSizeColumn(1);
                sheet.autoSizeColumn(2);
                sheet.autoSizeColumn(3);
                sheet.autoSizeColumn(4);
                sheet.autoSizeColumn(5);
                sheet.autoSizeColumn(6);
                sheet.autoSizeColumn(7);
                sheet.autoSizeColumn(8);
                sheet.autoSizeColumn(9);
                sheet.autoSizeColumn(10);
                sheet.autoSizeColumn(11);
                sheet.autoSizeColumn(13);


                try {
                    wb.write(outputStream);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
```

Comment: just rename file name and try with ".xls" file extenstion and check its working or not ? or share your exportToExcel() method also.

Comment: Dear Vinit, i need .xlsx,Method above Mention.

Comment: Yes dear, Just need to confirm, its also not working with xls then, there is some coding, and xls is working then it just problem related to XSSF object which includes XSSFWorkbook, XSSFCell, XSSFCellStyle, XSSFRow. that's why I am asking

Comment: It create the .xlsx file but when i opened "invalid file format or Extension".xls working  proper after changing the XSSFWorkbook to HSSFWorkbook.

Comment: <af:button text="Export to Excel" id="b5">
                <af:fileDownloadActionListener method="#{viewScope.routeDefineForm.exportToExcel}"
                 filename="RouteDetail.xlsx"
                 contentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" />
            </af:button>

Comment: import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook; use this import in your class.

Comment: <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.15</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.15</version>
        </dependency>  both version must be same